# Is there something wrong in casting from void pointer (to create a generic storage)?

Tags: c++, string, casting, void-pointers

I'm trying to create a generic storage class in C++. If you look at the code bellow, I'm want to store maps of `string` / `AnyType` and access them.

```
  class StoresTestC
  {
  public:
    template < class SettingsType >
    std::map< std::string, SettingsType >* getStore(std::string const&);
  private:
    std::map< std::string, void* > stores_;
  };

  template < class SettingsType >
  std::map< std::string, SettingsType >* StoresTestC::getStore(std::string const& name)
  {
    if (stores_.count(name) > 0)
    {
      void* temp = this->stores_[name];
      return (std::map< std::string, SettingsType >*)(temp);
    }
    else
    {
      std::map< std::string, SettingsType > * result = new std::map< std::string, SettingsType > ();
      this->stores_[name] = result;
      return result;
    }
  }
```

I see two obvious dangers in doing so:

1. If I call it with a wrong `SettingsType` / `name` I will call a wrong cast which as far as I know (I may be wrong) will lead to an undefined behaviour.
2. It will create a memory leak, but I have a solution for that (which was two long too be disclosed here).

Is there anything else that can go wrong and you can you forsee ?

Comment: Why not a `std::map` of `boost::any`s ?

Comment: Have you checked out the [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) library? It can be a useful way to have containers that store anything.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want a `std::map< std::string, boost::any >`, but one map per type...

Comment: ... but I could use a `std::map< std::string, boost::any > >` where the value is actually a map...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take a step back and make sure you *really* want to do this. Then look at your design one more time.

OK, you still need this capability?

Use `std::map<std::string, boost::any>` where the `boost::any` is always a `map` type. Then when you use `any_cast` or whatever mechanism to get the item back out, you're guaranteed that it's the right type or it throws so you never risk undefined behavior. Additionally since the `any` is by value you don't have a possible memory leak floating around either.

I should also note that in your original solution if you use a `shared_ptr<void*>` it would remember how to delete the original type stored in that `shared_ptr` thus removing the memory leak you mentioned.

EDIT: I can't see any other obvious technical problems with something like this. However note that having such a map is possible/likely to cause *cognitive* ("grokking") problems for future maintainers, and does increase the complexity of the code somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good idea. But back to my question, is there any other issue besides the one I've mentionned?

Comment: @jules The one you mentioned is a **BIG** one, as you can take from the answers around here. As long you're not absolutely sure that no one else but you are using this interface, and you will remember what you've been doing there I won't call such _'design'_ a good idea ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right with your doubts about point 1 (point 2 should be solvable as you mention, but think about destructors of the contained maps should be called correctly).

I won't let go such interface into the wild without providing a simple mechanism that clients keep up `SettingsType` and the `std::string` 'typename' representation in sync. A simple typo can mess up the whole thing. I think that `boost::any` will just express this with an exception as soon you try to cast the value to the desired/expected result type.

Why do you need `std::string` representation here at all? If you use RTTI for example you can hide the key used for `stores_` using `typeid()`.

Comment: RTTI is a good idea, but I'll lose the ability to have two maps of the same type. But I can add the RTTI information to the `ValueType` of my map and check agains it... but then it's like rewriting what has been done in `boost::any`

Comment: `boost::any` won't at least let you down with undefined behavior, as Mark B's answer says.  
But there may be cases when you can't use boost or exceptions or even RTTI (I'm working in embedded field for example where we face such situations). I usually get around this then using an `enum` for the type(-ids) that is extensible for clients and can be explicitly bound to the type in question using a template method specialization (I'm hiding this in macros for convenience). The compliance check is done at compile time then (look for 'static checks').

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to pass the type as a template parameter to get the map anyway, would it do to just have one map per type?

```
namespace StoresTest {
  template<typename T>
  struct MapStruct {
    static std::map<std::string, T> the_map;
  };

  template<typename T> std::map<std::string, T> MapStruct<T>::the_map;

  template<typename T>
  inline std::map<std::string, T>& getStore()
  { return MapStruct<T>::the_map; }
}
```

Then for example you can get a map with value type `Foo` by doing

```
std::map<std::string, Foo>& foo_map = StoresTest::getStore<Foo>();
```

You no longer need a `string` to name the type, but that could be added in if you have other reasons to want it.

Comment: But if the type of values in the map isn't known until runtime, you can't do anything with it!  Unless the value types all inherit a common abstract base class, in which case the map should just contain pointers to the ABC.

Comment: I don't really like the static bit... and it needs to be able to have several maps of the same type with a different key.